# How to check argument value formatting before controller method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

In my controller I have a method such as bellow:

```
public QueryResult<TrsAccount> listExclude(String codeAccount, String searchFilter, String order, int pageNumber,
     int pageSize){}
```

But before executing this method I have to chech if:

```
Assert.TRUE(codeAccount.matches("^[0-9]{1,20}$"));
```

Because this is very frequent in my application and it is not only this case, I want a general approach to check the argument format. The way I'm using now is the use of AOP, in which:

```
@Aspect
public class HijackBeforeMethod {

@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *)")
public void controllerBean() {
}

@Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
public void methodPointcut() {
}

@Before(value = "controllerBean() && methodPointcut()", argNames = "joinPoint")
public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

  MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
  Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
  String[] paramNames = signature.getParameterNames();
  for (int count = 0; count < paramNames.length; count++) {
     String tempParam = paramNames[count];
     Object tempValue = args[count];
     if (tempParam.toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase("codeAccount") && Assert.isNotNull(tempValue)
           && Assert.isNotEmpty((String) tempValue)) {
        Assert.TRUE(((String) tempValue).matches("^[0-9]{1,20}$"));
     }
  }
}
}
```

As you can see, this is very rudimentary and error prone code snippet. Is there any better solutions??

Comment: Just don't... Use an object and validate that, with either JSR303 validation or a custom validator.

Answer (score 1):

Using AOP in Controllers is not really recommended. A better approach would be [to use JSR 303 / JSR 349 Bean Validation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-validation), but that would probably require wrapping the string in a value object, which is then annotated accordingly.

If you insist on solving this with AOP, [you'll probably need a `ControllerAdvice`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice)

Comment: How can I do that with ControllerAdvice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just like [@Sean Patrick Floyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342852/sean-patrick-floyd) said, using `Bean Validation` is more advisable.

Firstly, define a class which extends from `org.springframework.validation.Validator` like:

```
@Component
public class CodeAccountValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return String.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        if (Assert.isNotNull(target) && Assert.isNotEmpty((String) target)) {
            Assert.TRUE(((String) target).matches("^[0-9]{1,20}$"));
        }
    }
}
```

Then add `@Validated` annotation to your controller like:

```
public QueryResult<TrsAccount> listExclude(
    @Validated(CodeAccountValidator.class)String codeAccount,
    String searchFilter,
    String order, int pageNumber,
    int pageSize) {
    ... ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but `CodeAccountValidator` not working.

Comment: Can parameter `codeAccount` use @RequestParam annotation?

Comment: Maybe, but here is not. does it make any differences?

Comment: Please do as @M. Deinum said, that is a standard solution. Mine needs some more settings, you can check [this](http://copyrightdev.tumblr.com/post/92560458673/tips-tricks-having-fun-with-spring-validators).

Answer (score 0):

Trying to solve this with AOP is something you shouldn't do. Instead use an object to bind your properties and validate that object.

```
public class QueryCriteria {
    private String codeAccount;
    private String searchFilter;
    private int pageNumber;
    private int pageSize;
    private String order;
    // Getters / Setters.
}
```

Then modify your controller method

```
public QueryResult<TrsAccount> listExclude(@Valid QueryCriteria criteria, BIndingResult result) { ... }
```

Then either use a Spring `Validator` which validates what you need .

```
public QueryCriteriaValidator implements Validator {

    private final Pattern ACCOUNT_EXPR = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{1,20}$");

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
       return QueryCriteria.isAssignable(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        final QueryCriteria criteria = (QueryCriteria) target;
        if (!ACCOUNT_EXPR.matcher(criteria.getCodeAccount()).matches()) {
            errors.rejectValue("codeAccount", "invalid.format");
        }
    }
}
```

In an `@InitBinder` in your controller method register this validator

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new QueryCriteriaValidator());
}
```

When using JSR-303 you don't need this and you could simply annotate the `codeAccount` field with the `@Pattern` annotation.

```
@Pattern(regexp="^[0-9]{1,20}$")
private String codeAccount;
```

The validation works nicely together with Spring MVC and error reporting using I18N. So instead of trying to hack around it with exceptions work with the framework.

I suggest a read of the [validation section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) and [binding section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args) of the Spring Reference guide.